# Anonymous scanner close

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

is there any possible way close Scanner that have been created as anonymous object:

```
new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

Eclipse generates warning in Java 8:

```
Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed
```

Answer (score 2):

In general: you need a variable that you can call `close()` on. Assign it to a variable, call `close()` (or use try-with-resources).

But in this specific case, there is no resource leak: you didn't open `System.in` (the JVM did, when it started up) (*), so you shouldn't close it, as would happen if you closed a `Scanner` wrapping it. The warning is erroneous.

---

(*) You might have used `System.setIn` to set `System.in` to something you *did* open. However, this is a rare and unusual case: you should still avoid closing `System.in`, and leave it to code which is specifically able to determine that the stream can be correctly closed, e.g. the code which created the `InputStream` that that you passed to `System.setIn`.

Comment: How is `System.in` not opened in this case? Can you please explain.

Comment: @Andy can you please explain your how is System.in not opened in this case?

Comment: @Oryksio it is *opened*, of course, just not by the user's code.